# LG G Pro E988 Youtube app crashes when I click a video

Tags: applications

I bought a second hand LG G Pro E988 and the youtube app crashes each time I try opening a video.

When I open the app it asks me to connect my gmail account to youtube and then when I click a video it crashes.

Also Id like to know whether there are known replicas for this phone?

Sorry If I have the wrong tag here, but couldnt find a popular enough tag for this phone

Comment: Have you tried updating youtube to latest version?

Comment: Yes. I did that..

Comment: Clear the data and cache in settings->applications->youtube. Any luck now?